# How does one lookup the error number in Windows EventLogEntry Message

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I am trying to read through the Windows Event log "Error" entry messages in  in c#.

```
  foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
  {
    if (log.EntryType.ToString() == "Error") 
    {
        Console.WriteLine( log.Message);
    }
  }
```

The output is "The XYZ service failed to start due to the following error: \r\n%%2"

while the entry I am looking for is

"The XYZ service failed to start due to the following error:\r\nThe system cannot find the file specified."

How does one translate from the id to the appropriate error message ?

Many thanks,
KG

Answer (score 0):

Event log messages are templates, something like:

`The %1 service failed to start due to the following error: \r\n%2`

An event log entry contains a message number and replacement strings to substitute for %1, %2, etc.

The .Net `EventLogEntry.Message` property does the substitution for you, so you should never see the %1, %2, etc.

It looks like the substitution is failing, perhaps because there aren't enough replacement strings (check the `EventLogEntry.ReplacementStrings` property) or the format string is malformed (it seems to have a stray '%').  Though neither of these explanations seem plausible if the log entry is coming from the Service Control Manager.